# Set the User's timezone when the only info is a UTC offset number.

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, datetime, timezone

Is there a timezone 'code' that includes the offset (for example: `-7`) that the function `date_default_timezone_set()` would accept? (I only have the offset number, and not something specific like `America/Phoenix`).

I'm setting timezones based off of Facebook's API, when I extract the user's information.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse timezone int to string (timezone name) (facebook api)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19489257/parse-timezone-int-to-string-timezone-name-facebook-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Time zones don't work that way.  A time zone offset only applies to a specific point in time.  Many time zones share the same offset at various times. Some are indistinguishable from others with an offset alone.

For example, `-7` could be MST, or it could be PDT.  It might be used with `"America/Phoenix"`, which is on MST year-round.  But it might belong to `"America/Denver"` which would use MST (-7) in the winter and MDT (-6) in the summer.  Or it might belong to `"America/Los_Angeles"`, using PST (-8) on the winter and PDT (-7) in the summer.

See also, the [timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info)

Regarding Facebook, it's only giving you the time zone offset as of the user's last login.  It is not necessarily even the correct offset for the current moment in time.

Comment: Can't I just recheck every time the user goes on my website? Or does the user have to log out of facebook and relogin in order for the timezone to change?

Comment: Facebook just calls JavaScript `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` when the user logs in and saves it in the user's profile.  If the offset changes before the user's next login (for example, crossing a DST transition), their profile will not reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a specific array.
For example,
$timezone = array("-7"=>"America/Phoenix", "-6" =>"oneplace/somewhere" ......... );

Therefore, you can use date_default_timezone_set($timezone[-7]);

Pascal

Comment: Hmm, good solution. Is there a pre-loaded array out there? Can't seem to find a good one.